# Please help me with my decimal to hex turbo assembly program

Tags: assembly, hex, decimal

I was working with my program which should convert decimal digit from 0 to 65535 to hex. The problem is that my program won't print 4 digit hexadecimal numbers. For example, it will print 5FF instead of FFFF or 711 instead of 1111 and i can't find the mistake. Please help.

Heres the code:

```
;***************************************************************
; decimal to hexadecimal
;***************************************************************

.model small

bufSize EQU 121

.stack 100h

.data

    bufSize DB  bufSize     
    read DB  ?              ;how many symbols
    buf  DB  bufSize dup (?)    

    msg  DB  'Please, enter decimal digit: $'
    enterr  DB  13, 10, '$'
    errormsg DB  'wrong input $'
    form     DB  'answer is: $'

.code

begin:
    MOV ax, @data       
    MOV ds, ax          

;****reads line****
    MOV ah, 9
    MOV dx, offset msg
    INT 21h         

    MOV ah, 0Ah
    MOV dx, offset bufSize
    INT 21h         

    MOV ah, 9
    MOV dx, offset enterr
    INT 21h         

;****algorythm****
    XOR ax, ax          
    MOV cl, read        ;how many symbols

    MOV bx, offset buf  ;first symbol to bx






check: 
    CMP cl, 0
    MOV ah, 9
    JNE loop0
    MOV dx, offset errormsg
    INT 21h         ;spausdiname rezultato žinutę
    JE ending

errorr:
    MOV ah, 9
    MOV dx, offset errormsg
    INT 21h         ;spausdiname rezultato žinutę
    JMP ending
loop0:
    PUSH ax
    PUSH dx
    XOR ax,ax
    XOR dx,dx
    JMP loop1


loop1:
    MOV dh,0Ah
    MUL dh
    MOV dl,[bx] 
    cmp dl, '0'
    JB errorr
    cmp dl, '9'
    JA errorr

    SUB dl,30h
    ADD al,dl

loop2:  
    INC bx          

    DEC cl          
    CMP cl, 0           
    JNE loop1           

    MOV cx, 16
    PUSH '$$'

Division:
    MOV dx, 0       
    DIV cx      ;[DX,AX]:10 = AX(remainder DX)
    PUSH dx     
    CMP ax, 0       
    JA  Division        

    ;printing
    MOV ah, 9
    MOV dx, offset form
    INT 21h         
    MOV ah, 2       
Print:
    POP dx      
    CMP dx, "$$"    
    JE  ending      
    CMP dx, 9
    JNBE above
less:
    ADD dl, '0'     
    INT 21h     
    JMP Print   
above:
    ADD dl, '7'     
    INT 21h 
    JMP Print   

    pop dx
    pop ax



ending:
    MOV ah, 4Ch
    MOV al, 0           
    INT 21h         



END begin
```

Thank you for your answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your multiplication step in the first loop:

```
MUL dh
```

This form of the `MUL` instruction takes an 8-bit register or memory operand (here `DH`), multiplies it with the 8-bit `AL` register, and stores the 16-bit result in `AX`.  Because this only allows 8-bit operands, it will only work correctly for input values up to 255.  If you want it to work for values up to 65535, you will need to use the form that multiplies two 16-bit values to produce a 32-bit result in `DX:AX` (and ignore the high 16 bits of that result, which are put in `DX`), e.g.:

```
MUL dx
```

But this will require shuffling your registers around, since you're currently already using `DL` to hold the current digit, and as I said, `DX` will get set to the high 16 bits of the 32-bit result.  In this situation, it might be preferable to use the `IMUL` signed multiply instruction, which is convenient because it can take up to 3 parameters (unusual for x86):

```
MOV dx,0Ah;
IMUL ax,ax,0Ah
```

This will set `AX` to the bottom 16 bits of the result and discard the top 16 bits.  The fact that the multiplication is signed doesn't make any difference here, because the bottom 16 bits will be the same in both cases.